# Visual studio documentation for c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have installed visual studio for c++
When i hover the mouse over a method or object, the studio offers to search the Internet for information about it. Is it possible to watch the documentation from ide, as in eclipse or intellij idea?

Comment: I have a feeling this is asking the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974312/vs2012-how-to-show-documentation-of-standard-c-libraries-via-intellisense. Granted it's 8 years later and I haven't heard of any effort on their part to document their headers inline.

Comment: Using WSL in Visual Studio allows you to use the GNU C++ libraries which do have inline documentation, but AFAIK this doesn't exist for MSVC.  
It's pretty telling that Microsoft's current sales pitch for windows is *"Do **more** with Windows"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. on the help menu there is the "set help preference" sub-menu that allows you to switch to a local help viewer. To use that you will have to download documentation sets you find of interest.

Comment: Which help menu is this? In Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition under "Help" in the menu bar, I don't see anything like "set help preference".